# Is there a way to have only two posts holding a 20ft wide main cross-beam of a pergola?

Tags: beam, pergola

Thinking of building a pergola to hold my jasmine up, and to create a shaded area outside our newly built extension.

The problem is the patio door opening is around 5m wide, so ideally I don't want any posts in front of that, in fact the further to the side it is the better. the total width I would like is 20ft wide by 5ft deep. 
Is there a way to have only 2 beams holding a 20ft wide main cross-beam?

Comment: Does [this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/66322/23448) answer your question?